# Is there a high-level overview of Cosmology and Prehistory?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, cosmology

Based on The *Voice of an Angel* and other tales, e.g. Atlantis, Father Wolf, has anyone tried to put together a very high level historical summary for the World of Darkness? Obviously a lot of this stuff is shrouded in myth, but i'm just looking for a  high level overview. It would be amusing of course if such a thing treated certain things as controversy, such as "is the city from *Voice of an Angel* Atlantis".

Answer (score 2):

There is a basic and incomplete timeline [on the White Wolf wiki](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_(WOD)). This isn't an easy task, as the new World of Darkness deliberately obfuscates history and refuses to give specific answers to questions in order to allow individual campaigns to provide their own spin.

Compare the old World of Darkness, where we know a great deal of detail thanks to the heavier focus on ongoing "metaplot."

Comment: but if we assume that the few details we've gotten are fact, or are some fractured view of it, then you can kind of start piecing the mirror together. I don't ever expect or want the metaplot. But it might be nice to have a view of it that's similar to what we have of some religions. Basically we conjecture much about our own history based on ancient artifacts, we could do the same for WoD whilst documenting the conflict. (some people think the earth is 6000 years old, and the God-Machine was made by the Soviets)